# <div> background-image doesnt work in Firefox but works on all other browsers

Tags: html, firefox, browser

I have checked everything possible on Stackoverflow and Google but couldn't find the proper answer :(
Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/tu41N11q

Comment: Post your code here (you can edit your post to do this), and please set up an example at jsfiddle.net, too. People will be much more likely to help solve the problem if they don't have to visit an external website to see the code!

Answer (score 0):

Set `div` Display attribute in your CSS.

for example:

```
background-image: url('logobg.png');
...
display:block;
```

or for inline:

```
display:inline-block;
```